# Access ViewController in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: swift

I want to access the initial view controller through

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
       return true
}
```

I happen to be using a navigation controller - but that doesn't matter really.

I've tried the following:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.rootViewController
UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window
application.windows[0].rootViewController
self.window?.rootViewController
application.keyWindow
```

and all are nil.

I want to use the storyboard and inject my dependency here. I don't want to instantiate a view controller here, I still want to use the initial view from the storyboard.

How can I access the view in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions - I want this for iOS12?

Comment: You can create the controller you want to start with then inject your dependencies, this will be more safe and accurate than depending on the initial view controller from the storyboard.

Comment: I can, but this isn't the idea here. I want to use the Storyboard rather than doing that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you want to access the TopMost ViewController presented, if so you can try to use this function in your AppDelegate

```swift
func topMostController() -> UIViewController? {
        
    if var topController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController {
        while let presentedViewController = topController.presentedViewController {
            topController = presentedViewController
        }
        return topController
    }
    return nil
}
```

To use this:

```swift
if let vc = self.topMostController() {
    // Your code to use vc instance of topMostController
}
```

Comment: UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController is nil, yet there is a presented view controller at the beginning of the application...

Comment: You can edit your question and add your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method or the lines of code showing how you add the initial viewController?

Comment: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is there - it returns true. The initial view controller is added through the storyboard, and is the initial view.

Comment: Ah ok, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions is one of the firsts methods executed in the life cycle of AppDelegate, have you tried getting the rootViewController using another of the AppDelegate lifecycle methods, for example in the applicationDidBecomeActive?